# Reuse a single set of preview annotations in Jetpack Compose across composable functions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

Taking first steps in Jetpack Compose, which is quite amazing except one annoying issue.

I have a constant set of previews: Normal, Dark and RTL:

```
@Preview(
    name = "Normal",
    group = "Screen",
    showBackground = true
)
@Preview(
    name = "Dark",
    group = "Screen",
    showBackground = true,
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
)
@Preview(
    name = "RTL",
    group = "Screen",
    showBackground = true,
    locale = "iw"
)
@Composable
fun JustAComposable() {
   ...
}
```

Let's just say, for example that I preview 50 composable functions. I need to copy-paste this set 50 times, which is absolutely incorrect.

Annotation inheritance is forbidden, so my question is: did anybody find a way to reuse the same set of previews across all composable functions?

The only 2 solutions which I could think of are:

- To use multiple custom previews **only** while developing.
- Partially reuse the previews - use compile-time constants for name and group.

## Edit:

I created a feature request to compose team to be able to create custom annotation and annotate the annotation with all of the previews I want to reuse.

This way I only need to use my custom annotation.

Can be tracked in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198165617)

Comment: Just an update, my feature request is marked as accepted

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The accepted feature request is now implemented and is available starting from Android Studio Dolphin and Jetpack Compose 1.2.0-beta01.

It is called **Multipreview Annotation**. More information about this feature can be [found here.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#preview-multipreview)

In order to use this feature, you must create a custom annotation class.

```
@Preview(
    name = "small font",
    group = "font scales",
    fontScale = 0.5f
)
@Preview(
    name = "large font",
    group = "font scales",
    fontScale = 1.5f
)
annotation class FontScalePreviews
```

and now you can apply this annotation class. For example:

```
@FontScalePreviews
@Composable
fun HelloWorldPreview() {
    Text("Hello World")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hell of a good news! I'm going to use it constantly :)

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel yes! Thanks for making the feature request :)