# How to create an annotation that composes other annotations in kotlin for composable functions?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to create an annotation called ***@MyComposablePreview*** that is composed of:

```
@Preview(
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO,
    showBackground = true,
    name = "Light Mode"
)
@Preview(
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
    showBackground = true,
    name = "Dark Mode"
)
@Composable
```

So that I could call it in a composable function like this:

```
@MyComposablePreview
fun CardPreiview() {
    //Code of preview
}
```

Is it possible to do this in jetpack compose? I tried to use annotated classes but I couldn't :/

Comment: This is a required feature!

Comment: See quite similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68635899), consider to +1 [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198165617).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```kotlin
@Preview(
  name = "Light",
  group = "Light",
  showBackground = true,
  backgroundColor = 0xffEEEEEE,
  uiMode = UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO,
  fontScale = 1f
)
@Preview(
  name = "Dark",
  group = "Dark",
  showBackground = true,
  backgroundColor = 0xff444444,
  uiMode = UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
  fontScale = 1f
)
@Preview(
  name = "Light - Large font",
  group = "Light",
  showBackground = true,
  backgroundColor = 0xffEEEEEE,
  uiMode = UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO,
  fontScale = 2f
)
@Preview(
  name = "Dark - Large font",
  group = "Dark",
  showBackground = true,
  backgroundColor = 0xff444444,
  uiMode = UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
  fontScale = 2f
)
annotation class MyComposablePreview
```